# Mongo aggregate rename field with $project?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to generate a aggregate result but rename some fields:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        "model.lang": "en"
    }},
    {$project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "model.title": 1,
        "model.address_en": "$address",
        "model.date": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } }
    }}
]);
```

As you can see I'm trying to rename "model.title" to "title", "model.address_en" to "address", and "model.date" to "date" .. without much luck though:

```
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
{ "model" : { "date" : null } }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 44):

Given the document of `articles`

```json
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cea763d43e3500f6768482"),
    "name" : "aaa",
    "model" : { 
        "lang" : "en",
        "title" : "b",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-02-25T07:04:03.414Z")
    },
}
```

Rename "model.title" to "title", "model.address_en" to "address", and "model.date" to "date" through

```
db.articles.aggregate([
    {$match: {'model.lang': 'en'}}, 
    {$project: {
        _id: 0, 
        'title': '$model.title', 
        'date': {$dateToString: {format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$model.date'}}
    }}
])
```

The result is

```
{ "date" : "2016-02-25", "title" : "b" }
{ "date" : "2016-02-25", "title" : "c" }
```

Comment: The `"model"` field in the question would not be an array, otherwise the attempts at projecting would show array brackets `[]` in the output. So it's really just the "left-side" to "right-side" part they have wrong.

Answer (score 23):

You can just use this

```
db.articles.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "model.lang": "en"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "title": "$model.title",
            "address": "$model.address_en",
            "date": {
                $dateToString: { 
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$model.date" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer

[andranikasl answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52913725/12692806)

### Explain

Your code does the opposite of what you say it does.
I will explain it inside of your code.

```js
db.articles.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        "model.lang": "en"
    }},
    {$project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "model.title": 1, // Wanted: title <- model.title // Result: model.title <- model.title // it should show you title inside model object
        "model.address_en": "$address", // Wanted: address <- model.address_en // Result: model.address_en <- address // address doesn't exist! thats why it shows nothing
        "model.date": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } } // Wanted: date <- model.date // Result: model.date <- date // date doesn't exist! thats why it shows nothing
    }}
]);
```

When a field you want to include does not exist, [$project ignores it](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-existing-fields) and that's why you don't see any wanted value in your output.

Comment: This would make more sense as a comment on the other answer.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I can't comment, my reputation is below 50.